# Getter for mutable object

Tags: java, javabeans, getter-setter

I read many articles as how to write right getter/ setter for mutable object as Date or Array. But when I changed this on

```
    public Date getDateTo() {
        return (Date) dateTo.clone();
    }

    public void setDateTo(Date dateTo) {
        this.dateTo = (Date) dateTo.clone();
    }
```

I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`. It means that I always shoul initialize date in (post)constructor?

Comment: Just add a simple if-else block if you really need to?

Comment: Do you mean check if dateTo = null use simple getter else copy?

Answer (score 1):

It `dateTo` is not initially constructed, then there is nothing to clone. So the answer is yes - you should initialize it.

Comment: Is it have a sense use this getters or just use simple getters?

Comment: That depends - if you want to prevent sistuations like this: `Date d = new Date(); foo.setDateTo(d); d.setMonth(12)` then yes. This approach is called [Defensive copying](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15). If on the other hand for some reason you want to allow such situations, then no :)

Comment: One more thing: if you have a setter in your object, then it's not longer immutable. And usually defensive copying is used to create immutable objects.